# Apache Solr on CloudFoundry

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am interested in deploying Apache Solr or ElasticSearch onto a CloudFoundry instance (Bluemix).

Is this possible? I could not find documentation or buildpacks...

Comment: I don't think there is a buildpack for it. The easier path would probably be to run it in a container or on a VM.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Elasticsearch by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/elasticsearch-by-compose/) service on Bluemix. It combines the power of a full text search engine with the indexing strengths of a JSON document database to create a powerful tool for rich data analysis on large volumes of data

If you want a different solution you can try using [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/getting-started-with-cloudant-ibm-bluemix/). Cloudant is a based on CouchDB DBaaS and it has support for indexed full-text search through Lucene and also a JSON based REST API. Take a look at [Cloudant Docs - Search Indexes](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/)

You could also try to use a container. Take a look here for some useful pointers: http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/07/08/making-logs-awesome-with-elasticsearch-and-docker/

Comment: Yes I noticed the Compose one, but it requires a separate Compose subscription. As for Cloudant, I'm not really looking for a database. I have an existing website and want to build a custom search engine for it.

Comment: You could use a container. Take a look here for some useful pointers: http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/07/08/making-logs-awesome-with-elasticsearch-and-docker/